# Determining the number of occurrences of a record

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables - student and interview - with values:

```
student
----------
sID  
sName  

interview
----------
sID  
date  
outcome = (OFFER, NOOFFER, HIRED)
```

And I have to list the sID of any student who has never received an offer but who has had more than five interviews.

I am having trouble figuring out how to determine if a student has had more than 5 interviews.  I know you can just count the records to see if the sID is listed more than 5 times, but I am not exactly sure how to format it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT s.sid
  FROM STUDENT s
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL -- more than five interviews
                FROM INTERVIEW i 
               WHERE i.sid = s.sid
            GROUP BY i.sid
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 5)
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL -- never received an offer
                    FROM INTERVIEW i
                   WHERE i.sid = s.sid
                     AND i.outcome = 'OFFER')
```

Comment: Ok this makes sense but I am not sure I understand the 'select null' statement - what exactly does that do?  This worked though, thanks so much!!

Comment: @user457666: In an EXISTS clause, the SELECT clause isn't used.  You could replace `EXISTS(SELECT NULL ...` with `EXISTS(SELECT 1/0 ...`, which should return a mathematical error for dividing by zero--it won't.  `EXISTS` is only interested in the `FROM` clause whatever after that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.sID,s.sName from
( select sID,count(0) as numInterviews 
  from interview 
  where sID not in (select sID from interview where outcome='OFFER') 
  group by sID
) as interviewCounts
join student s on s.sID=interviewCounts.sID
where interviewCount>5
```